# Determining when user stops interacting with macOS app

Tags: swift, macos

I want to hide my app's UI whenever the user interacts with any UI element outside my app.
For example, 
1) if the user invokes spotlight 
2) if the user clicks another app
3) if the user clicks on the menubar

[My app runs as an agent (LSUIELEMENT=true), so it doesn't own the menubar even when active, hence point 3 above]

I am using the following method in my `AppDelegate`

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // code to hide UI
}
```

This function gets called only in scenario 2 above (i.e. when the user clicks another app) but not for the other 2 cases.

How do I handle all cases of my app "losing focus" so to speak?

Comment: You'll probably need Accessibility permissions for this.

Comment: ok, how would I do it if I had accessibility permissions?

Comment: Global event tap.